# In App Purchase Objective C Status from appStoreReceiptURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit, in-app-subscription

I am new in Objective c I found

```
NSURL* url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSLog(@"receiptUrl %@",[url path]);
```

for check In App Purchase Status for validation or something like this.

how can I get this : as **NSString** ( `INITIAL_BUY,CANCEL`)

.INITIAL_BUY Initial purchase of the subscription.
.CANCEL Subscription was canceled by Apple customer support.
.RENEWAL Automatic renewal was successful for an expired subscription.
.INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL Customer renewed a subscription interactively after it lapsed, either by using your app’s interface or on the App Store in account settings.
.DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_PREFERENCE Customer changed the plan that takes affect at the next subscription renewal.

Answer (score 0):

The `url` you have, is just the location of the receipt, so you first need to read the receipt file:

```
- (NSData *)loadReceipt
{
    LogMethodCall

    NSURL *url = NSBundle.mainBundle.appStoreReceiptURL;
    if (!url) return nil;

    NSError *error;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:&error];
    if (data) return data;

    NSLog(@"Error loading receipt data: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    return nil;
}
```

Now you have the receipt data, you can convert it to `NSDictionary` and view its contents:

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[self loadReceipt]options:0 error:&error];
if (!error) {
   NSLog(@"%@", json);
} else {
   NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

Comment: `JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.`